# Reducing complexity of a method

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a method that does several tasks. It is part of the business logic of the application, but it is poorly readable because of the many `if-then` and `try-catch` blocks and the many `log` calls.

```
public class MyClass {     

boolean createReport, sendReport, warnIfErrors;

public void archiveAll() {

    if (createReport) {
      //... ...
    }

    if (sendReport) {
      //... ...
    }

    if (warnIfErrors) {
      //... ...
    }

}
```

The idea is to move the tasks into ad hoc methods and have an "archiveAll" method that may be understood at a glance:

```
public void archiveAll() {

    doCreateReport();

    doSendReport();

    doWarnIfErrors();

}
```

But as doing this, two problems arise:

1. if all methods use a local variable, I'll move it as a class field, but this is not good design
2. I want to move the test `if (createReport)` into the method `doCreateReport` too, because part of the complexity derives from the tests that are done. This makes the sub methods poorly cohesive though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of making variables class fields, just parameterize the function and pass the values around. This has another big advantage that your code will now become more unit-testable. I always promote to have each method to be as independent as possible as it helps in UT.
2. If you had the name changed to checkAndCreateReport then, will you still think that way:)

Comment: 1.yes and higlight the inter-realtions between the parts too. 2.I'm Very intrested in methods names like checkAndCreateReport.I think that in library code(proxy patterns,sql access,low-level functions)the approach is somewhat "down-up" you have to come up with a class with methods that do what they say they do, no less(fail with errors)no more(be cohesive).But the businness code must be readable,maybe top-down designed.I first write a process that requries steps "doA","doB","doC" then I go into details of when exactly do each thing.So I can have an idea of the steps a process takes at a glance

Answer (score 7):

If you have **a lot** of local variables that are shared between them it might make sense to make a private class to store them together, perhaps even do something like:

```
MyReport report = new MyReport(); // or MyReport.doCreateReport(); if it makes more sense
report.send();
report.warnIfErrors();
```

Again, it really depends on whether the function is currently big enough to warrant something like this.

If you can get away with just passing those common variables as parameters without having huge lists of parameters, do that.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can also pass the required data as arguments to the methods.
2. I would do the check before calling a method. If a method is called doCreateReport it should actually **do** that.

Comment: 1. yes, but the higher the number of variable grows, the less significant as arguments they are. think a method with 10 arguments... 2.of course i should, but i'm more intrested in changing the name in a correct one than move complex tests just for naming.

Comment: IMO a method that silently does nothing unless some obscure flag is set is more confusing that an explicit if.

Comment: Or you could rename methods to doCreateReportIfRequested(), doSendReportIfRequested(). That way you will know that methods behavior is conditional.